# Avoiding double-runs on merge requests - except merge_requests not working

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to make gitlab run 1 stage on merge_requests (and NOT on the push on the branch - so I only get ONE 1 for a merge_request) 
AND make gitlab (actually the same - but I'm okay with having to define it twice if necessary) stage - on all branches (but NOT on merge_requests)..

I have tried this:

```
# Builds for all - except snapshots (branches) - as we would otherwise have 2x build run on merge_requests
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
      - tags
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
  script:
    - ./build/build.sh ${CI_JOB_ID}

#EXACT copy of above - ONLY for snapshot builds
build-snapshot:
  stage: build
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - merge_requests
    - test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
  script:
    - ./build/build.sh ${CI_JOB_ID}
```

and the same with except: refs: .. (ie. advanced) - both yield the same result..  appearently gitlab does not see that there is a merge_request for the branch - so it runs it both for the branch, and for the merge_request :(

I have found the following issues which didn't help:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13445

Comment: I need to run pre and post tests (pre before build and post AFTER deploy has finished) ONLY on merge_requests - so it wouldn't work to have "the common stages" - run on the branch and then the rest on merge_request - as they would not wait on each other - so I could not ensure post-test was run ONLY after build-snapshot was run :(

Comment: and as I am talking to a k8s cluster (in snapshot-deploy) - I get a conflict as both runs - try to rollout the same helm name - and it sometimes hits in between so the none-atomic check for if it already exists - sometimes does not catch it - so I get a failure and stopped pipeline instead.

Comment: I can find NO variables in the branch run - that exposes that a merge_request pipeline is actually going to be kicked off also.. :( - ie. I have NO way of avoiding this :(

Comment: I opened https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/61849 - with what I see to be the most precise description of this issue - which I see as being a bug in gitlab.